# Like Query not working in RepoClass

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I am having following query.i am not getting output Please help how to retrieve data according to search key word Symfony&MongoDB.

```
class UsersRepository extends DocumentRepository {

    public function getUserByFirstLetter($letter) {


      $allusers   = $this->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->field('name')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$letter.'.*/'))
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();
```

}
}

I want to get result using LIKE operator.

Thanks
Advance

Answer (score 0):

You have return your result:

```
class UsersRepository extends DocumentRepository {

    public function getUserByFirstLetter($letter) {

        return $this->createQueryBuilder()
            ->field('name')->equals(new \MongoRegex('/.*'.$letter.'.*/'))
            ->getQuery()
            ->execute();
    } 
}
```

Comment: But this does not make any difference when i fire this query it is running as infinite loop and hang my system.I do not know what is exactly Symfony work with.Please Guide accordingly.Relay Appreciable